# Vertical Scrollbar is not Working while trying with Mouse Wheel#FF,Chrome

Tags: javascript, extjs, scroll, extjs4

I have a grid with around 8 rows and 10 columns(Ext 4.2.1-with JS Code) and I got a "vertical scrollbar" as the data size is more than min data size.But while trying to move the scrollbar using "mouse wheel",its lagging in Firefox(version:54.0.1),Google(version:59.0.3071.115).

I created the Grid with one of the columns is locked. I noticed that when grid column(s) is locked the `mouseonwheel` scrolling is very slow(When I am scrolling with my cursor on locked column. Scrolling happens smoothly when the cursor is on unlocked column.)

Here is my column configuration

```
columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name',locked   : true},
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1,lockable : false },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone',locked   : true }
    ],
```

Here when my cursor is on `Name` and `phone` , Scrolling is happening smoothly. But when I am trying to scroll with cursor on `Email` Scrolling is not happening as expected. (Means scrolling is hard)

Here is my fiddler. [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22eb) You can give a try.

How to overcome this. I am using ExtJS 4.2.1

Comment: Did turning off smooth scrolling actually fix the problem? Do you have the same problem in any other site? I use ExtJS grids daily with Chromium and FireFox and never had any issue with scrolling. Is the problem reproducible on another computer?

Comment: Thanq for your quick response. 
and yes it will fix the problem in FF,and they are locked grids. I believe this is an issue related to "Locking of Grids" .

Comment: I created a sample "LOCKED GRID" and there also the same problem exists.


https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22gv

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I click elsewhere, the grid scrolls normally. If the grid has focus, it is unbelievably slow. Do you really need the grid to be locked? The grid has [`onLockedViewMouseWheel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.locking.Lockable-method-onLockedViewMouseWheel) and [`onLockedViewScroll`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.locking.Lockable-method-onLockedViewScroll) methods. Sounds like something related to your problem. The methods also have their counterparts for normal view for comparison, what is being done differently.

Comment: @MarthyM I updated my question. Can you please have a look. Please check the fiddle in mozila or chrome.

Comment: Well, now the scrolling is completely disabled on the grid. How did you achieve that? I don't see any configuration relative to grid overflow.

Comment: I can see the scrolling(with lagging) is happening there. Can you please check now, once again. Here is the link. 

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22eb

Comment: If you think my answer is correct, please approve it, so that others with the same problem can find it more easily.

Comment: @MarthyM 
Firstly thank you soooo much for your answer.
I checked your solution with my sample grid and its working very fine :-)
But I have to check with the actual grid(I will check with in 4/5 hours), that's why I am not approving your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you override [`onLockedViewScroll`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.locking.Lockable-method-onLockedViewScroll) method in your grid and set it as an empty function, it should do the trick.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    ...
    onLockedViewScroll: Ext.emptyFn,
});
```